# Google sheets : onEdit all sheets available

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

looking for some help with Google Apps script
I've got this script :

```
SHEET_NAME = "1";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A3:G100";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 2, ascending: true},
{column: 3, ascending: true},
{column: 1, ascending: true}, 
];

function onEdit(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
}
```

And I'm simply trying to make it work in all sheets, can someone help me out ?

Comment: About `I'm simply trying to make it work in all sheets`, in your situation, for example, even when only a cell of a sheet is edited, you want to run the script for all sheets. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes this is correct !

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A3:G100";
SORT_ORDER = [
  { column: 2, ascending: true },
  { column: 3, ascending: true },
  { column: 1, ascending: true },
];

function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  multiSortColumns(sh);
}
function multiSortColumns(sheet) {
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
}
```

Comment: Got an error : 
 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
onEdit @ Code.gs:9`

Comment: you do not launch this script in the editor, onEdit will be automtically launched when a new data in introduced in your sheet

Answer (score 0):

As posted in Discord, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
function onEdit() {

    const SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A3:G100"
    const SORT_ORDER = [
      { column: 2, ascending: true },
      { column: 3, ascending: true },
      { column: 1, ascending: true }, 
    ]

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                  .getSheets()
                  .forEach(sheet => {
                     sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE)
                          .sort(SORT_ORDER)
                  })

}
```